# rails - passing regex to list of allowed attributes for sanitize method

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitization

Is it possible to pass regular expression to the list of allowed html attributes for sanitize method in rails3? In my particular situation I would like to allow all attributes starting with `"data-"`

Either on sanitize call

```
sanitize(my_string, :tags => %w(div span), :attributes => my_regular_expression)
```

or in application.rb like

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = 'id', 'style', my_regular_expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm... computer says no.

```
irb(main):018:0> my_string = "<div style=\"color:red;\" id=\"abcd\">abcd-def></div><span class=\"blah\">abcghi</span><a href=\"http://mylink.com/\">mylink</a>"
=> "<div style=\"color:red;\" id=\"abcd\">abcd-def></div><span class=\"blah\">abcghi</span><a href=\"http://mylink.com/\">mylink</a>"
irb(main):006:0> sanitize(my_string, :tags => %w(div span), :attributes => ['id'])
=> "<div id=\"abcd\">abcd-def></div><span>abcghi</span>mylink"
irb(main):005:0> sanitize(my_string, :tags => %w(div span), :attributes => [/id/])
=> "<div>abcd-def></div><span>abcghi</span>mylink"
irb(main):020:0> sanitize(my_string, :tags => %w(div span), :attributes => /id/)
NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for /id/:Regexp
```

Would be great feature, though. You could add it as a feature request on rails.

Comment: Um - no drive-by downvotes please... let me know why you think this answer is not useful... :)